# socket programming with ioctl TIOCOUTQ

Tags: c, linux, sockets, raw-sockets

Just a simple question, I am doing a raw socket programming:

```
fd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
```

and was pulling the the send buffer using:

```
bytes = sendto(fd, &buffer, send_size, 0,(struct sockaddr*)&socket_addr, addr_size);

ioctl(fd, TIOCOUTQ, &bytes);
while(bytes>0)
    ioctl(fd, TIOCOUTQ, &bytes);
```

if the bytes returns 0 and exit the while loop, does it guaranteed that the data is sent out of the device ? if not how do I actually check if the data is sent out of the device?

Comment: The `send()` function will take care of sending the data out of the device. The man page of send(2) states _On success, these calls return the number of characters sent. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately._

Comment: sorry i am using a sendto

Comment: `send()` just like `sendto()` returns the number of bytes sent. But this doesn'nt necessarily mean, that these bytes _really_ already left the wire, it might be stored in a socket buffer and wait for sending. `TIOCOUTQ` retrieves the size of the socket buffer, if it's empty, it has left the linux networking subsystem. This is as close as you can get. It still might be buffered in the driver or the network card itself, so you can never be absolutely sure it is on the wire, but in general, it does what you expect.

Comment: @Ctx I believe the output from send only refers to data being queued. It does not guarantee it was actually sent out.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh Hm, this is what I wrote, correct?

Comment: It is. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used to drive TX enable line when of RS-485 transceiver to ensure all bits are out:

```
void WaitTxDone(unsigned int messageSize)
{
    //wait for tty TX queue to become empty
    int queued = 1;
    while (queued > 0)
        ioctl(m_port->getPortHandle(), TIOCOUTQ, &queued);

    //number of nanoseconds it takes to transmit messageSize bytes (10 is 8 bits + start + stop)
    unsigned int txTime = ((float)(messageSize * 10) / m_baudrate) * 1000000000;

    //assuming it won't take longer than one second
    struct timespec delay = {0, txTime};
    nanosleep(&delay, NULL);
}
```